# Assign spot color in an existing CMYK pdf/tiff by using ghostscript

Tags: ghostscript, cmyk

I have a CMYK pdf/tiff and want to assign one of cmyk color as a spot color(named cmyk).

How to assigns／defines spot color in cmyk pdf/tiff by using ghostscript？

I just know that spotcmyk can convert spot to cmyk but how about reversed ?many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of any way to do this in Ghostscript, particularly not when starting from a PDF file.

Comment: I can convert the pdf as other formats like tiff. Does KenS know the command of ghostscript to do so?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand this question. Yes I know how to specify a different device to Ghostscript. What has that to do with your original question ?

Comment: I mean that If the format is in tiff, do you know what syntax can assign /re-define the existing cmyk to spot color in ghostscript? Do you think I can use some specific ICC profiles to do so? if no, do you know any other librarys/tools to do so? thankyou so much.

Comment: I cannot think of any way which will allow you to redefine an existing CMYK value as a /Separation colour, no matter what the input format. No you can't do this with an ICC profile, no I don't know of any other libraries which will do this. You could write a PostScript program which redefines setcolor and setcmykcolor, as well as redefining the image operator. Ths would not be trivial and would likely be defeated by many real-world PostScript programs, though PDF might work acceptably. Realistically, if you made the document incorrectly, fix the original, don't try and hack it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ghostscript to [separate channels in to single TIFF files](http://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Devices.htm#TIFF). However you would need some other software to "recompose" the channels in to a CMYK+n file.

Depending on your platform, you could use Photoshop or [GIMP](https://docs.gimp.org/nl/plug-in-compose.html)